# Access database with reports to multiuser web interface

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ms-access, web-applications

I have a client that ask me to convert an Access database to something web based.
The database has 20 tables, 10 input forms (input of data is not done directly into tables), about 100 queries and 20 reports.

1. I don't mind using mssql/c# but I would prefer using php/mysql.
2. The client would like to have the ability to create himself custom report like it's possible in Access (WYSIWYG interface to select tables and fields and possibility to add header, footer, labels, etc.).
3. The solution can be something licensed but I would need something flexible as this is the first step of a bigger project.

Thank you very much in advance for your ideas/help.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the DB to Mysql and use an odbc driver to link access to the mysql db for report creation, what is the issue?

Comment: Well, the reports won't run in the web browser, so they won't really be "web based", as is a requirement in the original question.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have some ideas about what to use as data input instead of the Access input forms and what to use to view and generate Access reports...

Comment: Well it was not clear that the reports had to be web based, I assumed that he wanted to re-implement the app using the same data structure and allow the "back office to do reports. If you need report generating in the browser , look at Brit but you will have to do a fair amount to define what types of custom you want to allow, Pentahoo is another possibility... Both are big steps up from access though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this tool](http://dbconvert.com/convert-accessforms-to-web-mysql.php) or [this](http://www.caspio.com/extend/platform-extensions/ms-access-database-online.aspx).